# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str WITH API

Tags: python, json, list, api

```
result = [{'line': 'johannsasuke@gmail.com:42ab89', 'sources': ['Taringa.net'], 'last_breach': '2017-08'}, {'line': 'johannsasuke@gmail.com:PEIN12345', 'sources': ['Evony.com'], 'last_breach': '2016-07'}, {'line': 'johannsasuke@gmail.com:sasuke12345', 'sources': ['Animoto.com', 'Collection 1', 'xSplit'], 'last_breach': '2019-01'}, {'line': 'johannsasuke@gmail.com', 'sources': ['xSplit'], 'last_breach': '2013-11', 'email_only': 1}]

for x in result:

   if result['email_only']==1:

     pass

   else:

     print(result['line'])
```

I'm trying to print the combos that are released with this api but am getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` is a list, so you probably meant `x`, as this is your item:

```
for x in result:
    if x.get("email_only") == 1:
        continue
    print(x["line"])
```

Prints:

```
johannsasuke@gmail.com:42ab89
johannsasuke@gmail.com:PEIN12345
johannsasuke@gmail.com:sasuke12345
```

NOTE: I used `x.get()`, because it returns `None` if key `email_only` doesn't exist in the dictionary (not throwing exception).

Comment: @NathanWilliamson, note the use of `continue` instead of `pass`. This is the convention for `for` loops.